# Merge the [european] tag into [europe]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

There are currently 7 [european](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european) questions and 515 [europe](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) questions; and it does not seem the former have anything special setting them apart from the latter.

I therefore suggest the former tag be merged into the latter. I don't even think a synonym is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has been merged into [europe](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe).

While you're right that it's probably not needed, I synonymised the two anyway.